# Unable to understand why this is not a height balanced binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am looking at LeetCode problem [110. Balanced Binary Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/):

> Given a binary tree, determine if it is height-balanced.
>
> For this problem, a height-balanced binary tree is defined as:
>
> > a binary tree in which the left and right subtrees of every node differ in height by no more than 1.

I have this input:

```
[2,1,3,0,null,null,4,null,null,null,5]
```

For this input, the expected output is `false`. Why is this not a height balanced binary search tree? I did look up the definition of what height balanced means, but maybe I am unclear of the direction in which to look at this tree to determine whether it is height balanced or not.

Comment: Where is this example taken from? Which source says it isn’t balanced? Also, as an FYI, it’s unusual to see a BST encoded as an array this way. (Binary *heaps*, on the other hand, are frequently represented like this.)

Comment: The problems on leetcode usually encoded these in an array this way. I used this example on an algorithm on leetcode that checks whether the tree is balanced or not , and it returned false . https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/

Comment: I added that info into your question.

Answer (score 3):

The tree represented by this array is:

```
        2
       / \
      1   3
     /     \
    0       4
             \
              5
```

The definition of what balanced means in this LeetCode exercise is:

> a binary tree in which the left and right subtrees of every node differ in height by no more than 1.

This is not true for the tree rooted at 3. Its left and right subtrees differ in height by 2.

Comment: Could you give some feedback on this answer? Did it suit your needs?